# How to setup an LPR printer?

Tags: release-freya

Using an Asus router to share a USB Samsung printer. The Print Server uses LPR and some Queue name. I can get this to work easily in Windows and PCBSD (FreeBSD), but Elementary OS it just sits there not detecting anything. With the other OS's, I had options to select which protocols to use, but Elemenary has nothing but some search bar.

I tried searching but no results showed, except for Ubuntu and the screens look different... So here I am. Thank You in advance

Comment: Okay, after some searching, I found out Elementary OS and Ubuntu (and probably other FOSS OS's like FreeBSD) use CUPS! was able to do something when I entered http://localhost:631 into a web browser. Now a printer shows up in the printers section of system setting, but if I wanted to use the add printer option, it don't work!

Comment: Please add this as an answer (not a comment) and mark your issue as resolved.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this as yet?

Answer (score 1):

Your user needs to be a member of the lpadmin group to have privileges to add a printer.
That is the default setting.
You can double check /etc/cups/cups-files.conf and look at the "SystemGroup" setting to confirm this.